# systematic trading reading fixed income

Tags: options, fixed-income, credit

I would like to expand my knowledge on systematic strategies in fixed income. I know there are a lot of articles on equity but these markets are different and I would like to know more. Are there good summary books or summary papers? Mainly interested in corp bonds, options, FX.

Answer (score 5):

AQR Capital Management has a number of good papers on the general topic of systematic investing. In particular, you might find "Systematic Credit Investing" by Frieda and Richardson (easy to find on the Internet) interesting; it addresses both corporate bonds (investment grade/high yield) and CDS.

Comment: Many papers on fixed income written by Antti Ilmanen, when he was at AQR Capital Management or before, are worth reading.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answer, many of the risk & analytics vendors sell factor based fixed income risk models which can be used in systematic ways.

https://www.msci.com/www/research-report/msci-fixed-income-factor-model/0655159886

https://qontigo.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/AXI_FS_FI_Factor-Based_R1-FINAL.pdf